# handing data returned from jquery get request

Tags: php, jquery

I have a simple jquery script as follows:

```
$('a').click(function() 
    {
        //get the id of the song we want to play
        var song_id = $(this).attr("id");

        //do a get request to get the information about the song
        $.get("http://www.site.com/v4/ajax/get_song_info.php", { id: song_id, }, function(data)
        {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
        //alert( song_id );
    });
```

I have gotten it to work and it returns several bits of data 'artist' 'title' 'song duration' and so on.

How do I process my 'data' so I can then update my page with each bit. In this case I want to set a series of '' to hold each of the values returned.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice would be to use a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) encoding.

Whatever server-language you are using, encode your data as JSON object and send it with
the mime-type `application/json`.

Javascript/jQuery side make a call to [.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) which is aquivalent to

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: callback
});
```

However, if you are using jQuery 1.4.x, you now have a JSON object in your data variable.
In a previous version you need to explicitly parse the incoming data into a JSON object. For instance

```
if(window.JSON) data = window.JSON.parse(data);
```

This will create a valid `Javascript Object` which you can treat and access like

```
data.artist
```

(Of course you need to create such an object structure serverside before sending)

Comment: I am using PHP so instead of echo 'whatever' i need to do whatever it is that PHP does to output a JSON object?